# Does Azure PostgreSQL support custom certificate for Authentication instead of username & password?

Tags: azure, postgresql-9.5, azure-postgresql

I am looking for certificate based authentication for Azure PostgreSQL , where we dont have to specify any password credentials.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security

What i understand from the above URL , is that  Azure PostgreSQL supports having certificate , in connection string, where there is no password specified.  So i am assuming , this is certifcate based authentication. Please correct me if i am wrong in understanding

Eg: **psql "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt host=mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com dbname=postgres user=myusern@mydemoserver"**

Instead of the BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt , can i use a different certificate or configure the PaaS service of Azure PostgreSQL to use other cert , like abc.crt , that is sslrootcert=abc.crt

In other words , does Azure PostgreSQL support Certificate based authentication.
Any good links would be appreciated

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today , the PaaS version , i.e. Azure Database for PostgreSQL doe not support certificate authentication